# addition of two dictionaries with negative numbers

Tags: python

Could someone advise on why addition of two dictionaries does not work? It appears that when the sum is negative, the results is dropped out of the dictionary. If one of the values is negative but the sum is still positive, the result shows in the addition.

```
dict_a = {'A':1, 'B':-2, 'C':3}
dict_b = {'B':-4, 'C':-5, 'D':6}

dict( collections.Counter(dict_a) + collections.Counter(dict_b) )
```

The result of the summation is:

```
{'A': 1, 'D': 6}
```

Comment: Ordinary dictionaries can't be added at all. Try `dict_a + dict_b` and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your title, I understood, you're tying to sum the values of two dictionaries. here is an approach without counter method

```
dict1 = {'A':1, 'B':-2, 'C':3}
dict2 = {'B':-4, 'C':-5, 'D':6}
 
for key in dict2:
    if key in dict1:
        dict2[key] = dict2[key] + dict1[key]
         
print(dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'B': -6, 'C': -2, 'D': 6}
```

Based on the suggestion by @Barmer:

```
from collections import defaultdict
 
dict1 = {'A':1, 'B':-2, 'C':3}
dict2 = {'B':-4, 'C':-5, 'D':6}

ret = defaultdict(int)
tests = [dict1, dict2]
for d in tests:
    for k, v in d.items():
        ret[k] += v

print(dict(ret))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': -6, 'C': -2, 'D': 6}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `else:` create the dictionary entry?

Comment: You can use `defaultdict()` or `.setdefault()` to avoid the need for the `if` statement.

Comment: thanks for all the comments. This works for me now

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter
> objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than
> zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or
> subtracting the counts of corresponding elements. Intersection and
> union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts. Equality
> and inclusion compare corresponding counts. Each operation can accept
> inputs with signed counts, but the **output will exclude results with
> counts of zero or less**.

See the highlighted portion, which explains why the negative counts are removed.

Comment: Note that you can use the in-place `.update` method to preserve such counts (the same way `.subtract` does for `-`).

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
a = {'A':1, 'B':-2, 'C':3}
b = {'B':-4, 'C':-5, 'D':6}
{k:a[k]+b[k] for k in (set(a) & set(b))}
# {'C': -2, 'B': -6}
{k:a[k]+b[k] for k in (set(a) & set(b))} | {k: a[k] for k in (set(a)-set(b))} | {k: b[k] for k in (set(b)-set(a))}
# {'C': -2, 'B': -6, 'A': 1, 'D': 6
```